# Dynamic Lambda In Html.LabelFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, lambda

I am trying to make a label for a dynamic property using an html helper from the razor engine. The view model is *not* strongly typed. My knowledge of lambda expressions is not very strong and I am unsure how to produce a dynamic expression that will fit this situation.

```
public class someModel<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

<strike>----</strike>

```
@model dynamic
@{
 string property = "FirstName";
}

@Html.LabelFor( m => m.Entity.property )
```

Which throws the error `An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`.

I looked into making dynamic expression trees but was unsure if that was overkill or necessary. How can I access properties of the `Entity` by using strings?

Entity could be a number of different types of classes. Those classes have fully defined data annotations such as `[Display(Name = "Some Name")]` and the reason I am trying to use LabelFor is to have access to those data annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible. You cannot use lambda expressions nor strongly typed helpers with dynamic values. You will have to use the weakly typed versions of those helpers:

```
@model dynamic
@{
    string property = "FirstName";
}

@Html.Label("property")
```

Yes, once you stop using strongly typed view models, lots of things and habits will have to change.

Comment: I see, I considered doing the rest with javascript since all the data is technically there it just lacks the nice support from strongly typed models. I am only attempting to make this generic view for crud views, and not for anything which would require more than the basics. I am tired of having views which are extremely similar in code.